# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler in Java 1.3

Tags: java, rmi

I need to run an rmi server on java 8 and call it from java 1.3;
when i use This code:

```
ITest service= (Test) Naming.lookup("rmi://172.16.1.24:1009/testRmiService");
String people = service.TestMethod("hamed" );
```

> "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler"

occurred. After that I add this to java.policy:

```
permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1009","connect, resolve";
```

this error will be shown :

> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested
>   exception is:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler

Please help me to call my rmi service (on java 8 ) from java 3

Answer (score 1):

You haven't run `rmic` on your remote objects, so you are getting dynamic stubs, and 1.3 doesn't understand those.

> After that I add this to java.policy:

Pointless. You aren't running a security manager, so policy file entries are not used.

Comment: Make sure to compile the stub as 1.3.